# Want to clear cache from webView in React Native CookieManager.clearAll(); Not Working in iOS

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

Want to clear cache from Reaact-native-webView in React Native, {CookieManager.clearAll();}-Not Working in iOS

Comment: So what is your code?

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    CookieManager.clearAll()
  .then((res) => {
    console.log('CookieManager.clearAll =>', res);
  });
  }

Comment: <WebView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            source={{ uri: this.props.navigation.state.params.datass }}
            onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
            renderLoading={this.ActivityIndicatorLoadingView}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            useWebKit={true}
            startInLoadingState={true}
          />

Comment: Mind putting that in context and editing it into your question?! It is quite hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: I need to clear the cache from webView when every time I launch the WebView

Answer (score 18):

You can use the Incognito property in WebView for clearing the cache while you want to lunch the WebView.

```
<WebView
........
incognito={true}
/>
```

Comment: This solution is better than others.
As huent-1493 says, `incognito` property works both on ios and android while `cacheMode` and `cacheEnabled` works only for android 
https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/880#issuecomment-812305097

Answer (score 6):

I had to clear the cache on logout, had to create a native module, and bridge it to React Native. This is the code:

```
// ClearWebviewCache.m
#import "ClearWebviewCache.h"
#import "WebKit/WKWebsiteDataStore.h"

@implementation ClearWebviewCache

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(clearWebviewIOS:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve reject:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject){
  
  NSSet *websiteDataTypes = [WKWebsiteDataStore allWebsiteDataTypes];
  NSDate *dateFrom = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore] removeDataOfTypes:websiteDataTypes modifiedSince:dateFrom completionHandler:^{
      return resolve(@"ok");
    }];
  });
}

@end
```

Header:

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface ClearWebviewCache : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

and you can then call this in React Native:

`await NativeModules.ClearWebviewCache.clearWebviewIOS();`